# How to check whether String contains "?" mark

Tags: javascript, html, string, substring

I want to check whether string contains "?" mark or not.
My string likes as 
"[https://suort.mmo.com/jira/browse/AAA-157?fousedCommentId=120209&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-120209](https://suort.mmo.com/jira/browse/AAA-157?fousedCommentId=120209&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3acomment-tabpanel#comment-120209)"

I want to check this url string included "?" mark or not using JavaScript.

Answer (score 4):

UPDATE: If you're using ES6, use [`String.prototype.includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes):

`const containsQuestionMark = myStr.includes('?');`

Otherwise, if you're stuck on ES5, [use `indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf)

```
var containsQuestionMark = myStr.indexOf('?') > -1;
```

Answer (score 2):

check this site:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf

the method indexOf returns -1 if it does not find the search term, so do this simple if statement

```
var s = 'string with a ? in it';

if(s.indexOf('?') != -1) { /* code if string has a ? */ }else{ /*code if string does not have a ? */ }
```

Comment: Thanks all I also found another method for this matter.var s = 'string with a ? in it'; s.(/\?/);